# Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module

Tags: python, anaconda, qgis

I am trying to open an Anaconda environnement in QGIS python console.
To do so, I imported subprocess and implemented the method
`x= subprocess.run(r'conda activate env_name,capture_output=True,shell=True)`
then `print(x.stderr.decode())`
to decode the erreur.
Actually, the same code would work in a vs code or idle console but won't in qgis python console.
Here is the error

```
Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\Python39\lib\site.py", line 73, in <module>
    import os
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\Python39\lib\os.py", line 29, in <module>
    from _collections_abc import _check_methods
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\Python39\lib\_collections_abc.py", line 12, in <module>
    GenericAlias = type(list[int])
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

I searched for several solutions but it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: better format code which you use.

Comment: x= subprocess.run(r'conda activate env_name,capture_output=True,shell=True)

Comment: format code in question, not in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found a solution finally. But, I am not sure if it's the optimal solution or not.
I tried to install QGIS from anaconda accordig to the command:

```
 1. open anaconda and create a new environment named ‘qgis_env’
 2. open anaconda prompt and write‘conda activate qgis_env’ 
 3. Write this command ‘conda install -c conda-forge qgis’
```

you can easily open qgis afterwords by writing qgis directly in the appropriate environment.